# How do i get the value of a custom checkbox using php in woocommerce wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I used the code below to add a custom checkbox.

```
<input id="my_field" class="" type="checkbox" name="my_field" value="08"/>
```

And I am trying to use

`$myfield = get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_field", true);`

in order to get the value of the checkbox but for some reason, it is failing to get the value.